# libdgx how to set style of TextButton?

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx

Using the [uiskin.json](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json) by default

It contains

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font, fontColor: white     },
toggle: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, checked: default-round-down, font:     default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red }
},
```

--

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
TextButton button = new TextButton("my button",skin);
```

if clicked, it will change color using `button.setColor(Color.RED);` This works well.

if clicked again, I want it to change back to the default style. I wrote the following but it causes an error

```
button.setStyle(new TextButton.TextButtonStyle());
```

The error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION GLThread 2812
java.lang.IllegalRuntimeException: Missing LabelStyleFont
```

I have the files default.fnt and default.png in my assets folder already. Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you have to do TextButton.getStyle() to get the style?